# Regarding div size

Tags: css, html

Basically, on one of the pages of my website, I have a div with 60% width, in which all of my content is stored.

My problem is, when I try the site on different, lower resolution monitors, Some of the content in the div ends up being cut out.

I don't want to increase the width, but I have no ideas on how to fix the issue without doing so.

Comment: Use percentages on the content too..

Comment: can you provide any code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use media queries to change the style rules based on factors like device-width and resolution:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries

For example, you could adjust the font-size in the div based on the size of the viewport